# Installing some packages on Ubunut using apt-get install without root privileges

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, package-management

At work, we have a Ubunut server to which people from intranet connect for using certain tools installed there. If certain user wants to install a particular software on Ubuntu but does not have root privileges, i.e. installing it only in his home area or something, is it possible to do so using Ubuntu package manager: apt-get install If yes, how?

I know other way would be get the source of the software build it yourself, and install the binary in home area of the user, but would like to avoid that route.

The reason we would like to allow this is 1) That tool is very specific to that project and would not want to install system wide. 2) There is no other intention of subverting or hacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following would work to install the package to ~/local/

Download the package as package.deb.

Then run

```
dpkg --install package.deb --instdir=~/local
```

It appears apt-get doesn't have the faculties to forward arbitrary flags to dpkg, so you might want to use it first in pretend (-s) mode to find dependencies.